# How to Validate SSH Public Key Format

Tags: python, security, encryption, ssh

I'm looking for a way to validate a user-given SSH public key; so it has to be a safe validation, given a user inputted public SSH Key.

Any idea on how I would do this? I'm completely lost on how to create a safe solution. I'm looking for something similar to the validation method that DigitalOcean does on new droplet creation.

Ideally I'd like a way to validate this in Python code without any external libraries.

Things I've attempted:

- Split the ssh-key into 3 parts, however I came to realise that even the ssh-rsa key is not necessarily 3 parts long
- I've also considered doing a base64 decoding on the key-part, however I'm unsure if it's safe
- Using ssh-keygen -l, I'm unsure if this is what I'm really looking for? Or if it is safe, given a user-inputted key

Comment: I guess that -l at least parses the public key, so if it fails after that then it may well be because of malice. But that goes back into *trusting* public keys which is another matter entirely, and can of course not be solved if your only input is the public key itself.

Comment: See also [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/453296/how-do-i-validate-an-rsa-ssh-public-key-file-id-rsa-pub), don't forget to check the return code.